# Magento change grand total

Tags: magento, events, observers

I have a requirement in which the customer has to pay only a certain percentage of the total amount online. The rest is paid physically. So if the customer buys a product of $100, then he has to pay only 5% of it, i.e. $5 only. So the grand total need to be $5 in cart, checkout, orders, invoice, credit memo and all. I tried to implement it by creating a new total like in the tutorial in the following [link](http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-example). But then I thought I didn't need to add a new total but just modify the grand total. So i tried implementing with observers, by observing the event *sales_quote_collect_totals_after* in which I changed the grand total and base grand total as required. But after save the grand total still changed to the original grand total and not the modified ones.
The following is the how I implemented the observer:

```
public function calculatePartialPrice($observer) {
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
    $baseGrandTotal = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $partialPrice = $grandTotal * 0.05;
    $basePartialPrice = $baseGrandTotal * 0.05;
    $quote->setGrandTotal($partialPrice);
    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($basePartialPrice);
    $quote->save();
}
```

And here is my config file:

```
<events>
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
            <observers>
                <partial_price_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>magesage_partialprice/observer</class>
                    <method>calculatePartialPrice</method>
                </partial_price_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
    </events>
```

Please suggest what is wrong with my code, or suggest a better way to implement this.

Comment: try changing grand_total & base_grand_total to subtotal and base_subtotal setters

Comment: well i tried $quote->setGrandTotal($partialPrice); and $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($basePartialPrice); But the change is seen in the observer function only but later the total is changed back to the original total.